# Explanation of derivation made at wikipedia.

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-astronomy

in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly#From_the_true_anomaly) A deriviation to convert true and eccentric anomaly. I am however quite stunned by a single line - trying to reproduce but after half a dozen sheets of paper I can't find how it is done.

The problem lies in the following:

$$\tan(E) = \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2} \sin(\theta)}{e + \cos(\theta)}$$

$$\tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1-e}} \cdot \tan \left( \frac{E}{2}\right)$$

I am really stuck in how to get from the first line to the second line (which is at wikipedia explained by a single word "also").

Comment: Please note that usually "also" isn't used for implications, but to introduce other things that will be used in the proof. It seems likely, though, that some clever application of trigonometric identities should allow you to transform one of those equations in the other one.

Answer (score 3):

Going backwards,

$$\tan(E)=\tan(2\frac E2)=\frac{2\tan(\frac E2)}{1-\tan^2(\frac E2)}\\
=\frac{2\sqrt{\dfrac{1-e}{1+e}}\tan(\frac \theta2)}{1-\dfrac{1-e}{1+e}\tan^2(\frac\theta2)}\\
=\frac{2\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin(\frac \theta2)\cos(\frac \theta2)}{(1+e)\cos^2(\frac\theta2)-(1-e)\sin^2(\frac\theta2)}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin(\theta)}{e+\cos(\theta)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the second equation can be derived from nothing but the first, and I don't see how the Wikipedia article implies that.

With $\cos(2\alpha)=\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$, thus $1+\cos(2\alpha)=2\cos^2\alpha$, and with $\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$, we have $\tan\alpha=\sin(2\alpha)/(1+\cos(2\alpha))$, and thus

$$\tan\left(\frac\theta2\right)=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$$

and likewise

$$\tan\left(\frac E2\right)=\frac{\sin E}{1+\cos E}\;.$$

Above the equations you quote, the article has

$$\cos E = \frac{ e + \cos \theta }{1 + e \cos \theta }$$

and

$$\sin  E =  \frac{ \sqrt{1 - e^2} \, \sin \theta }{1 +  e \cos \theta }\;.$$

Substituting those in the formula for $\tan(E/2)$ and then using the one for $\tan(\theta/2)$ yields your second equation.

Comment: P.S.: I guess Yves' answer suggests that the second equation can indeed be derived from nothing but the first; still, the Wikipedia article doesn't say that this is how it is best to be derived.